# Speflow tests getting skipped

Tags: selenium, specflow, asp.net-core-2.1

Im using .Net core 2.1 for my speclow selenium project
and im getting the following error

SpecFlow+Runner Evaluation Mode: Please purchase at http://www.specflow.org/plus to remove test execution delay.

How to avoid it without purchasing a license?

Comment: Do you mind to use bit older version of specflow? that wont cause issue of license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 15th of January SpecFlow+ is now free of charge for any number of users.
You can get a free license at https://specflow.org/specflow-license-request/